# Proving a limit to Infinity

Tags: real-analysis

The question is to prove that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (n-7\sqrt n) = \infty$$

I know that $n > N$ implies $1/S_n < \epsilon$.  How do I show rigorously?

Comment: Given $M>0$ you should show that there exist $N>0$ such that for ever $n$ greater than $N$ the inequality $n-7\sqrt{n}>M$ holds.

Comment: I understand what I am supposed to do, but how do I prove that n-7√n > M?  I see it for an example like n^2 + 1/n > M. but not this.

Comment: You can also use the equation $$n-7\sqrt{n}=n(1-(7/\sqrt{n}))$$ and note that $(1-(7/\sqrt{n})) \to 1$ for $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $M>0$ you should show that there exist $N>0$ such that for every $n$ greater than $N$ the inequality $n-7\sqrt{n}>M$ holds. Now, observe that

\begin{align}
n>64&\implies&\quad\sqrt{n}&>8\\
&\implies& n&>8\sqrt{n}\\ 
&\implies& n-7\sqrt{n}&>\sqrt{n}\\
\end{align}
Since $n>M^2$ implies $\sqrt{n}>M$, when both inequalities $n>M^2$ and $n>64$ are satisfied
$$n-7\sqrt{n}>M$$
So, for every $M$ we can take $N=\max(64,M^2)$.

Comment: It follow you until you say "it is easy to see" that $$n > M^2$$

Comment: I am close to understanding it.  I need to mill it over.  Thanks.

Comment: $n>64$ implies $n-7\sqrt{n}>\sqrt{n}$ and, if also $n>M^2$, then$\sqrt{n}>M$ which means $$n-7\sqrt{n}>\sqrt{n}>M$$